# Do I need SpannableStrings or should I choose another solution?

Tags: android, listview, textview, spannablestring

I've made a ListView from data that I get from a DataBase.

```
@Override
                    public void mostCommonResults(String array) {
                        results=array;
                        pieces=results.split(";");
                        sorted=new String[pieces.length/2];
                        int firstNumber=0;
                        int secondNumber=1;
                        for(int i=0;i<sorted.length;i++){
                            sorted[i]=pieces[firstNumber]+"                             "+pieces[secondNumber]+" occurence";
                            firstNumber+=2;
                            secondNumber+=2;
                        }
                        list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(ThirdActivity.this,R.layout.list_items,R.id.list_elements,sorted);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
```

Result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7iu3.png)

Then I set OnItemClickListener for the ListView so when the User clicks on a specified item I want to give it to the TextView like on the second picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OYaJ.png)

I give the datas to the TV as a SpannableString

```
if(selectedNumbers.getText().toString()=="Selected Numbers"){
                            pieces=0;
                            //position=which item has clicked
                            String temp=sorted[position].substring(0,2);
                            //if the number has only 1 digit
                            if(temp.substring(1,2).equals(" ")){
                              selectedNumbers.setText(temp.substring(0,1));
                                pieces++;
                            }
                            //if the number has 2 digits
                            else{
                                SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(temp);
                                //SpannableString array...Is it necessary?
                                selected[pieces]=ss;
                                ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View textView) {
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                                        super.updateDrawState(ds);
                                        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                                    }
                                };
                                selected[pieces].setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                                selectedNumbers.setText(selected[pieces]);
                                selectedNumbers.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                                selectedNumbers.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                pieces++;
                            }

                            selectedTextView.setEnabled(false);
                            selectedTextView.setOnClickListener(null);

                        }
```

I can't figure out how could I do when the User clicks on the TextView specified part, remove only that part(SpannableString) and keep the others, furthermore set back the OnClickListener for that ListView element whose number removed by the User.
It would allows the User change his/her mind which 6 numbers he/her want finally on the TV.

list_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView style="@style/TextDesign"
    android:id="@+id/list_elements"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the layout for the listview? If you're using a LinearLayout with two textviews for the right and left texts, then in the `onClickListener` you can just get the left textview by ID and add it to the TextView. Need more details to give you a full answer

Comment: I've added the layout.xml
I'm using only one textview.

Comment: Is there a constraint that you cannot use two textviews? For example, one for the number 32 and one for the text 195elofordulas? That would make things so much easier for you.

Comment: You're right! I change my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! I'll post the answer for your benefit! :)
For the ListView Layout, you can have something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_narrow">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your OnClicklistener for the listview, you can get the TextView like this

```
TextView leftTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.left);
```

And just do this to add it to the TextView in your heading

```
String text = headingTextView.getText();
headingTextView.setText(text+leftTextView.toString());
```

I didn't test these functions but hopefully you get the idea! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really appreciate your helpfulness! :)

Comment: No worries! If you can, can you upvote my answer!? :)